# how retrieve value from json file

Tags: javascript, json, axios

```js
axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data.destination);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

i am using axios library to retrieve data from an API which return below json object.

```json
 "data": Object {
    "data": Object {
      "at_dstn": false,
      "at_src": true,
      "at_src_dstn": true,
      "awaiting_update": false,
      "destination": "INDB",
      "ir_train_name": "JODHPUR - INDORE Ranthambore SF Express",
      "is_run_day": true,
      "journey_time": 975,
      "new_message": "Train hasn't started yet. But all looks good.",
      "notification_date": "2022-08-21",
      "run_days": "MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN",
      "seo_train_name": "Intercity Express",
      "source": "JU",
      "spent_time": 0.13,
      "std": "2022-08-21 05:00",
      "success": true,
      "title": "Train starts at 05:00",
      "train_name": "JODHPUR - INDORE Ranthambore SF Express",
      "train_number": "12466",
      "train_start_date": "2022-08-21",
      "upcoming_stations": Array [],
      "user_id": 0,
    },
    "message": "Success",
    "status": true,
    "timestamp": 1661021331914,
  },
```

in this json file, i want to retieve destination value which can be access by

```
response.data.destination
```

but it returns value as undefined. so is there somthing i am missing

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: how do you get this object ?

Comment: i have updated the question with code. i am using axios library and it return that json file.

Comment: Don't use runnable snippets for code that can't run. Use normal code formatting. Having said that: just console log the response and see what's _actually_ in it.

Comment: i have console log response and it contain headers, data, method etc info from API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios returns the response with data as shown in your response. If you want to get the destination values use this.

```
response.data.data.destination
```